# Material-ui Typography with router link always underlined

Tags: reactjs, react-router, material-ui

I can't seem to get rid of the underline when I add a React-Router link to a Typography element, even if `underline="none"` or `"hover"` is selected.

from useStyles:

```
title: {
    display: "none",
    [theme.breakpoints.up("sm")]: {
      display: "block",
    },
  },
```

from render (the Typography element is in a Toolbar, not sure if that makes a difference):

```
          <Typography
            className={classes.title}
            variant="h6"
            noWrap
            component={Link}
            to="/"
            color="textPrimary"
            underline="none"
          >
            Your Text Here
          </Typography>
```

in browser:
[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to specify the following in your Links CSS:

```
textDecoration: "none",
boxShadow: "none"
```

Comment: <Typography sx={{ textDecoration: "none" }}>

Answer (score 4):

https://material-ui.com/api/typography/ it's seems like `<Typograpphy/>` don't have attribute underline, but `<Link>` has https://material-ui.com/components/links/#links.
should your text be a link? Maybe you could try something like this:

```
<Typography
  className={classes.title}
  variant="h6"
  noWrap
  //component={Link}
  //to="/"
  color="textPrimary"
>
  <Link to="/" underline="none">
    Your Text Here
  </Link>
</Typography>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use textDecoration: 'none'

```
import Typography from '@mui/material/Typography';
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

<Typography
    className={classes.title}
    variant="h6"
    noWrap
    component={Link}
    to="/"
    sx={{ textDecoration: 'none' }}
    >
    Dashboard
</Typography>
```